# DNS stops resolving after few minutes. On WiFi only

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, dns

I have Windows 10 x64 Enterprise. This happens only on WiFi network. Doesn't matter if I'm using build in or USB adapter.

I tried using Google DNS, Open DNS and default DNS. Doesn't matter which one I use.

This happens on most networks. Not all, but most.

nslookup still works. But ping or anything else on PC is unable to resolve hostnames.

Restarting Dnscache (DNS Client) service does not fix the problem.

Only way to fix problem (for few minutes) is to disable and enable WiFi.

ipconfig command:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:    
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::984c:78ee:5ecd:9381%15
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.103
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: some similar problems are reported seem to be solved with a reset of winsock in an administrative command shell: "netsh winsock reset" after that a reboot is needed an probably a new configuration of static ip adresses